# AngularJS how to get an array that adds a number to an element in a function and later distracts it with another function

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

So I want to make an application that needs an array that adds a number to an element if the `id` of the part from `this.parts` is mentioned in `this.parts[partId].comp[i]`. But if I try to run the function it sais in the alert `NaN` instead of the value of the element. How does it come that it is not a number and how can I fix it?

app.js:

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('kompileApp', []).controller('partsList', function($scope){
    this.parts = parts;
    // this.ps = partSelected;
    this.order = orderString;
    this.ap = aantalProducts;
    this.aa = addedArray;
    this.aaString = addedArrayString;
    this.jaddString = justAdded;
    this.cc = compCount;

    this.jadd = function(partId){
        this.jaddString = parts[partId - 1].id + ': ' + parts[partId - 1].name + ', ' + parts[partId - 1].price + '| ';
        this.aa[partId - 1] = this.jaddString;
    };

    this.arrayToString = function(){
        for (i = 0; i < this.aa.length; i++){
            if(this.aa[i] != undefined){
                this.aaString = this.aaString + this.aa[i];
                this.aa[i];
            };
        };
    };

    this.stillPossible = function(partId){
        for(i = 0; i < this.parts[partId - 1].comp.length; i++){
            if(this.parts[partId - 1].comp[i] != undefined){
                this.parts[(this.parts[partId - 1].comp[i]) - 1].canAdd = false;
                this.cc[this.parts[(this.parts[partId - 1].comp[i]) - 1]] = this.cc[this.parts[(this.parts[partId - 1].comp[i]) - 1]] + 1;
                alert(this.cc[this.parts[(this.parts[partId - 1].comp[i]) - 1]]); //this alert gives 'NaN' (Not a Number)
            };
        };
        this.parts[partId - 1].added = true;
    };

    this.nowPossible = function(partId){
        for(i = 0; i < this.parts.length; i++){

            for (j = 0; j < this.cc.length; j++){


                if(this.parts[i].comp[j] != undefined || this.parts[i].added === true){
                    this.cc[this.parts[(this.parts[i].comp[j]) - 1]] = this.cc[this.parts[(this.parts[i].comp[i]) - 1]] - 1 ;

                    if (this.cc[this.parts[(this.parts[i].comp[j]) - 1]] === 0){
                        this.parts[(this.parts[i].comp[j]) - 1].canAdd = true;
                        alert('123');
                    };
                };
            };
        };
        this.parts[partId - 1].added = false;
    };
});

this.ccInit = function(){
    for (i = 0; i < this.cc.length; i++){
        this.cc[i] = 0;
    }
};
var parts = [
{
id: 1,
name: 'vitamine A',
price: 3,
canAdd: true,
added: false,
comp: [2, 5]
},
{
id: 2,
name: 'vitamine B',
price: 5,
canAdd: true,
added: false,
comp: [1]
},
{
id: 3,
name: 'vitamine C',
price: 2,
canAdd: true,
added: false,
comp: []
},
{
id: 4,
name: 'Opium',
price: 20.95,
canAdd: true,
added: false,
comp: []
},
{
id: 5,
name: 'steroids',
price: 12.5,
canAdd: true,
added: false,
comp: [1]
}
];

var orderString = "i am the orderstring...";
/*
for (i=0;i<parts.length; i++){
orderString = text = $('p' + i).text();
}
*/
var aantalProducts;
aantalProducts = 0;

var addedArray = new Array(parts.length);
var addedArrayString = '';

var compCount = new Array(parts.length);

var justAdded = '';
})();
```

html:

```
<ul class="plist">
        <li ng-repeat="part in pl.parts | orderBy:'+price'" ng-hide="part.added || !part.canAdd" class="plLi">
            <div class="plistDivName">
                {{part.name}}   <!--alternatief: <span ng-bind="part.name"></span> -->
                {{part.price | currency : "&euro;"}}    <!--| currency om 2 cijfers na de komma te krijgen        alternatief: <span ng-bind="part.price | currency"></span> -->
            </div>
            <div class="plistDivButton">
                <button ng-click="pl.ap = pl.ap + 1; pl.jadd(part.id); pl.stillPossible(part.id)" ng-show="part.canAdd" class="plistbutton">add</button> <!-- veranderd value van pl.parts.added naar true -->
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- list van ge-adde parts-->
<div class="plistDiv">
<p class="plistP">your product:</p>
    <ul class="plist">
        <li ng-repeat="part in pl.parts | orderBy:'+price'" ng-show="part.added" class="plLi">
            <div class="plistDivName">
                {{part.name}}
                {{part.price | currency : "&euro;"}} <!-- | currency om 2 cijfers na de komma te krijgen -->
            </div>
            <div class="plistDivButton">
                <button ng-click="pl.nowPossible(part.id); pl.ap = pl.ap - 1; pl.aa[part.id - 1] = ''" class="plistbutton">remove</button> <!-- verranderd value van pl.parts.added naar false -->
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you debug your code? Try debugging with the developer tools of your browser (e.g. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/)

You can set break points and check the value before and after your addition.

Additionally, use angulars $log.log("The value is:", someValue); to log out objects and values.

My guess is, that the value is not what you think it is (undefined, String etc).

Use $log or alert to show the values you use to get your result (you can also do this via debugging if you know how)

```
alert(partId);
alert(this.parts[partId - 1]);
alert(this.parts[partId - 1].comp[i]);
alert(this.parts[(this.parts[partId - 1].comp[i]) - 1]);
alert(this.cc[this.parts[(this.parts[partId - 1].comp[i]) - 1]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Revisit the below line in your code:

```
this.cc[this.parts[(this.parts[partId - 1].comp[i]) - 1]] = this.cc[this.parts[(this.parts[partId - 1].comp[i]) - 1]] + 1;
```

There are two points to be noticed over here:

1. The first is that `this.cc` array is an array with blank values.
2. The second and the most important
       **this.parts[(this.parts[partId - 1].comp[i]) - 1]** in the above line will identify an object rather than a number, so
       **this.cc[will not be numerical value]**, so the above line will not give the desired results.

Comment: yes, that seems to be the case. How can i check the value of the object instead of the object itself?

Comment: As Java script arrays can work with number or string values in the index part, so you can use use some unique property(either number or string) of the object for this. Because if you will use object at the index place all the objects will be converted into some string value like "[object Object]" acting as the key/index for that value.

Comment: Just to demonstrate what I said in the last line of my above comment, refer the below example:

var a1 = []; 
var o1 = {id:1}; 
var o2 = {id:2}; 
a1[o1]=2; 
a1[o2]=4; 
for (var k in a1) {
 console.log('key=', k, ', value=', a1[k]);
}